# Why $\mathbb{N} \subset V_\omega$ and $Seq(\mathbb{N}) \subset V_\omega$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $V_\omega$ denote the set of all hereditarily finite sets.

Let $Seq(\mathbb{N})$ denote the set of all finite sequences from $\mathbb{N}$. That is, $Seq(\mathbb{N}) = \cup\{^n\mathbb{N}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where $^n\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all functions from $n$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Why $\mathbb{N} \subset V_\omega$ and $Seq(\mathbb{N}) \subset V_\omega$?

I just started to learn some basic set theory, the set $V_\omega$ is quite confusing for me.

Comment: $\operatorname{Seq}(\Bbb{N})$ is a set of finite sequences of $\Bbb N$?

Comment: The von Neumann ordinal $\omega$ is certainly a subset of $V_\omega$. But what _exactly_ do you mean by finite sequence?

Comment: Here a finite sequence is just a function whose domain is some natural number.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $n$ is hereditarily finite, then so is $n\cup\{n\}$. So by induction $n\in V_\omega$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Also, if $a,b$ are h.f. then so is $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ (or whatever way you use to define "ordered pair"). Therefore, any *finite* subset of $V_\omega\times V_\omega$ is $\in V\omega$. So by the first result, especially every finite sequence of natural numbers is $\in V\omega$ (it suffices that such a sequence is a finite set of pairs of h.f. sets).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $V_\omega$ is an inductive set. If $x\in V_\omega$ then $x$ is hereditarily finite, and so $x\cup\{x\}$ is also finite, and its transitive closure is finite (it is the transitive closure of $x$ with the addition $\{x\}$).

Since $\varnothing\in V_\omega$, it means that every integer is in $V_\omega$. Therefore $\Bbb N$, or $\omega$, is a subset of $V_\omega$.

As for the finite sequences, note that if $f$ is a finite sequence of integers then for some $n\in\Bbb N$ we have that $f$ is a sequence of integers smaller than $n$. It is not hard to show, then, that $f$ is also hereditarily finite and therefore in $V_\omega$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\mathbb N\subset V_\omega$ because all element of $\mathbb N$ is hereditarily finite. Note however that $\mathbb N\notin V_\omega$, as $\mathbb N$ itself is not finite.

For the strict inclusion, you can observe that $\{2,3\}$ is in $V_\omega$ but not in $\mathbb N$.
For $Seq(\mathbb N)$, it is included in $V_\omega$ only if you are talking about finite sequences, i.e. $Seq(\mathbb N)=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N} \mathbb N^k$.

If on the contrary you define $Seq(\mathbb N)=\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$, then we have $Seq(\mathbb N)\notin V_\omega$.